# Show Short Text Field As Check Box

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 database with a Linked SQL Server table.  The Sql Table has a field called `R2S` that is a nvarchar(100) data type.  When this was linked into Access 2013 it was changed to short text.  The field will always only hold 2 values -> Yes or No (I can not change the data type in SQL unfortunately).

On a user form how can I base a checkbox value of either checked or uncheked based off the Yes/No value that currently exists in the SQL Table?  Yes would mean checked, No would mean unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
=([R2S]="Yes")
```